# Window not disappearing on Screenshot

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image, screenshot

i want to take a screenshot of my screen when i press a button on a window. The problem is, the window shall disappear before taking the screenshot.

Here's my code:

MainWindow:

```
private void OnButtonScreenshotClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
{
    this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    ScreenCapture capture = new ScreenCapture();
    this.Close();
    capture.Show();      
}
```

ScreenCapture(To show the screenshot)

```
public ScreenCapture()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.ScreenCaptureImage.Source = Screenshot.TakeFullScreenshot(width, height);
}
```

As you can see i try to Hide the window before i initialize a new ScreenCapture-Window. I also tried to put a delay with Thread.Sleep, but that doesn't work as well.

Here's my code to take a screenshot:

```
public static ImageSource TakeFullScreenshot(int width, int height)
{
   Image bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height);
    {
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            graphics.CopyFromScreen(new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 0), bitmap.Size);
        }
    }
    return GetImageStream(bitmap);
}

private static BitmapSource GetImageStream(Image myImage)
{
    var bitmap = new Bitmap(myImage);
    IntPtr bmpPt = bitmap.GetHbitmap();
    BitmapSource bitmapSource =
    System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
          bmpPt,
          IntPtr.Zero,
          Int32Rect.Empty,
          BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
    //freeze bitmapSource and clear memory to avoid memory leaks
    //bitmapSource.Freeze();
    //DeleteObject(bmpPt);
    return bitmapSource;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this instead of this.Close();

```
this.Hide();
```

Comment: Okay, that was easy. Thanks! I will accept your answer as soon as I can.